# Azure AD B2B users don't show any apps under myapps

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have Office E3 and Azure AD Premium licenses assigned.

Apps switched '*on*' under the license but no apps show up in myapps.microsoft.com. The same setup works fine for regular users and shows the Office suite.

How do I get the apps to show up?

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the user with the licenses assigned and their empty access panel?

Comment: @Saca heya I've since  been told that this is a bug and they're working on a fix. Thank you for the response

Comment: Cool! Can you please add this info as an answer and flag the question as answered?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do that ! New to the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classified as a Bug. Being worked on by Microsoft. No need for further investigation as I'm hoping they'll patch and fix at some point soon.

Answer (score 0):

A way around this is to make custom apps for the specific apps that you want to share. Set the SSO to SAML and the sign in address to the direct link to the app you want to publish to B2B users.